# Hermitian Matrix true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, hermitian-matrices

I am trying to prove or disprove the statement:

If $A,B$ are n by n complex matrix, then if $A+B$ is Hermitian, then both $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.

Is this statement true or false?

Comment: Can you do it for $2\times2$ matrices?

Comment: Note that $A$ is Hermitian means the conjugate transpose of $A$ is equal to $A$. Can you show that if that is true for $A$ and $B$, what the means for $A+B$?

Comment: @wlpj2011 The problem is about the other direction.

Comment: it is in another direction

Comment: Oh, I misread, I would recommend trying to find a $ 2 \times 2$ example, as recommended above.

Comment: I did find an example, but I still cannot sure that I wouldn't find a counter example..

Comment: If you know any non-Hermitian matrices, you could try finding a way to add it to a related non-hermitian matrix to get a hermitian matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A real matrix is Hermitian if it is symmetric. Use

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

LHS is hermitian but the matrices in RHS are not Hermitian.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-i&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&i\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a matrix, which is not hermitian and $B=-A$, then $A+B$ is hermitian.